# regular expression whole word replace, whitespace only

Tags: regular-expressions

Some modes treat underscores as word boundaries.

I am using `evil` via `spacemacs`.  I am trying to use a vim/sed style `:%s/foo/bar/g` search and replace, but operate **only on whitespace delimited words**, not underscores.

As an example, if I have the following:

```
num_foos_
foos_
```

and I want to rename only `foos_` to `bars_`.

I have tried the following:

- `:%s/foos_/bars_/g` : *matches both `num_foos_` and `foos_`*
- `:%s/\bfoos_/bars_/g` : *matches both `num_foos_` and `foos_`* (I guess because `_` is a word boundary, so `\b` matches `num_foos_`)
- `:%s/\bfoos_\b/bars_/g` : *matches neither* (I guess because `_` is a word boundary, and there is no word after the trailing `_`)
- `:%s/\<foos_/bars_/g` : *matches both `num_foos_` and `foos_`* (I guess for the same reasons as `\b`)

How can I match only `foos_` and *not* `num_foos_`?

Answer (score 3):

The required syntax is **`%s/\_<foos_\_>/bars_/g`**

As mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5941448/955273) SO answer:

> The regexp `\<foo\>` or `\bfoo\b` matches `foo` only when it's not
>   preceded or followed by a word constituent character ([syntax
>   code](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Syntax.html)
>   `w`, usually alphanumerics, so it matches in `foo_bar` but not in
>   `foo1`).
>
> Since Emacs 22, the regexp
>   [**`\_<foo_bar\_>`**](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Regexp-Backslash.html)
>   matches `foo_bar` only when it's not preceded or followed by a symbol
>   constituent character. A symbol constituent is either a word
>   constituent or a character with syntax `_`. Most programming mode
>   define `_` to be a symbol constituent.